# How to formulate "The $n$ smallest"

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I know how to formulate the set of all $x$ with minimal distance to $y$ with $d(x,y)$ being the distance function:
$\{x \mid \arg\min d(x,y)\}$

But how do I formulate the set of the $n$ closest $x$ to $y$ using $d$?

**EDIT**: Basically I want a "Highscore" and cut it after the $n$-th entry (to be nit-picky: it's a "Lowscore")

Comment: What is "$arg min$" supposed to mean?  I've never seen that.  I surely wouldn't understand what the set above should be.

Comment: Also note that in the general case you probably can't define what you want to define.  What if there are ten points which all have the _same_ distance to $y$?  What is _the_ set of the seven closest points to $y$ in that case?  (Hint: There's more than solution.)

Comment: $arg~min$ is the argument leading to the minimum: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max#Arg_min . I just could not find out how to add the $x$ below the formula. In the case you described, it would be ok in my case to have undefined behaviour, i.e. it does not matter which of the points having the same distance is in the set. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: Thanks, I have to admit I've never seen that before...

Comment: No problem - although I even knew this notation, I just recently failed in a math-unrelated exam to remember it :-D

Comment: You can try to adjust the 'order statistic' lingo to suit your needs. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic

Answer (score 2):

How about this : 
$$ \{ x : d(x,y) \leq d(u,y) \text{ for all } u \}. $$

**EDIT**

$$ \{ x_i : d(x_i,y) \leq d(u,y) \text{ for all } u \text{ and } i \le n\}. $$

Could be a bit ropey.

Comment: Thanks. But this would only work if there were n $x$ having the same (smallest) distance. And this set is not limited to n elements (EDIT: I think it is just a redraft of the formula above; it lacks the "n closest" formulation)

Comment: @PhilLab It isn't clear to me how this definition restricts the size of the set to any fixed number of elements.

Comment: n should be an upper limit to the set's size (cf. the question's last sentence): Basically I want a "Highscore" and cut it after the n-th entry (to be nit-picky: it's a "Lowscore")

Comment: @PhilLab Oh, I see. I've just read your edit and next comment.  I misunderstood the cut-off issue.

Comment: @EDIT: sloppy notation is ok in my use case. But the proposed edit requires the list of $x_i$ to be already sorted - and then we would not need to look at the distance function, just: $\{x_i : i <= n\}$

Comment: @NickR: The second version doesn't make sense I'm afraid.

Comment: @Frunobulax Ya, well, I did say it was a bit ropey.  And a "bit" is quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If, as you said, you are using the notation described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max), then your example above is wrong as this notation already denotes a set.  It would simply have been $\arg \max d(x,y)$ or better $\arg \max_{x\in X}d(x,y)$ to make clear where your $x$ are from.

As to your question, there's no way to write $\{x \mid \dots\}$ in such a way that you at the same time define a set of elements with certain properties and also constrain the set to have exactly (or at most) $n$ elements.

I'd simply write it in English: "Let $A$ be a set of exactly $n$ points such that no point *not* in $A$ has a distance to $y$ which is smaller than that of any point *in* $A$."

---

However, you could write something like this:

$$ \{ x \in X \mid \text{there are at most } n \text{ points } z \text{ with } d(z,y) < d(x,y) \} $$

But that wouldn't be exactly the same you were asking for, especially if several points can have the *same* distance to $y$.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately several points can have the same distance to $y$.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with this, inspired by Nick R's answer:

$\{x_i \mid i \leq n\}$ with $d(x_i,y) \leq d(x_{i+1},y)$ and $d(x_1, y) \in \arg \min d(x_i,y) $

what do you think?

Comment: Looks good.  As a mathematician, I would probably write something like this: Let the sequence $(x_i)_{i=1,\dots,N}$ be an enumeration of the set of all points with $d(x_i,y)\leq d(x_j,y)$ whenever $i<j$.  The set we're interested in then is $\{x_i \mid i \leq n\}$.  The fine points here are a) that as already mentioned there's probably more than one possibility for such a sequence and b) to make it clear that the sequence counts each point exactly once (i.e. that it is bijective).  Using a phrase like "enumeration of" should make that clear for most readers.